# display full string in bootstrap modal using jquery instead of first word

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using php to fetch a name from a db and using jquery when I click on a button I want to display that name as html inside  a bootstrap modal box . The problem is the name has spaces and I can only display the first word . `ex. "my name " displays "my" instead of "my name"`

My code :

html element created with php that holds name and toggles the modal  :

```
 <div class = 'card__footer'>
   <h3> ".$partner["storeName"]." </h3>
   <a data-toggle = 'modal'  data-val = ".$partner["storeName"]." data-target='#partnerModal' >  
    <button type = 'button'>View Reviews </button>
   </a>
</div>
```

jquery to insert name as html in modal on show :

```
 $('#partnerModal').on('show.bs.modal' , (e)=>{
    if(e){
     var partner = $(e.relatedTarget).data('val'); //gets only first word !
     console.log(partner); 
     $("#partnerTitle").html(partner);
    }


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the problem of AJAX, it's your source. If you check your rendered source in browser by console (e.g.), you'll see data-val missing it's double quotes; right syntax is `data-val="something"`.

So, your source would look like `data-val=my name` ... so name would be interpreted as another attribute. To avoid this, just use the right syntax for setting attributes.

In your case:

```
<div class="card__footer">
   <h3>' . $partner['storeName'] . '</h3>
   <a data-toggle="modal2" data-val="' . $partner['storeName'] . '" data-target="#partnerModal">  
    <button type="button">View Reviews</button>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work since I have created this element using php and takes single quotes ' ' as error

Comment: Well, the problem is your PHP code at this time: you have to mask your used quotes the right way. If you use string concatenation like above, set it into single quotes - keep double quotes, mask single quotes by backslash inside and return your string into the AJAX answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove spaces from the start and end of a value using trim function. This function is available in both PHP & JavaScript.

**PHP**

```
$str = "my name ";
echo trim($str,"my name "); // returns "my name" without quotes.
```

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "my name ";
echo str.trim(); // returns "my name" without quotes.
```

Use these code according to your desired need. They can help you in fetching first name only.

Comment: I don't want to fetch only first name I want the full word with spaces

Comment: Show your PHP Code then.

Comment: I did my html element is created with php from a database